# JavaScript - Using jQuery find as matching variable, then doing something?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an Variable which get's item name. I want to do, so it will get item name and then search it from .item card class. If it matches, then do something.. Is something like that possible to do?

Code to match that item name

```
var leiaelu = $(".item-card").find("img.title");
leiaelu.removeClass("red lighten-1 white-text selected-item");
```

Way it get's item name

```
var removedname = $(this).text();
```

Where should I put that removedname variable in that code?

Question is: How could I make that `leiaelu` match `removedname` from that class img title. If it is a match, then it does that removeClass line?

Here's HTML where is the img title located (original one which it should match)

```
<li class="col 2 zoomIn animated" style="padding: 8px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; animation-delay: 0s;">
   <div class="card item-card waves-effect waves-light" data-itemnaaaaaaaaaaaame="★ Butterfly Knife | Crimson Web (Field-Tested)" style="margin: 0%; min-height: 295px; width: 245.438px; border-radius: 15px; height: 245px;" id="2761454276">
      <div class="iteam" style="text-decoration: underline;text-align: left">Butterfly Knife | Crimson Web</div>
      <div class="condition" style="text-align: left;text-size:13px">Field Tested</div>
      <div class="center-align" style="padding:6%">
         <img title="★ Butterfly Knife | Crimson Web (Field-Tested)" draggable="false" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpovbSsLQJf0ebcZThQ6tCvq4iSqODxMajum25V4dB8xLjD9tjwjgK1_kZoYT30ctKVegM7NFyGrwK5yee90ZDt6ZmazHNluCQ8pSGKMl3kzfs/200fx200">
         <div class="" 'floatvalue'="">
            Float: 0.11503319442272186
            <div class="bitskinscomp" style="font-weight: normal;font-size:12px">BitSkins Price: $111.43 (You save: $-38.15)</div>
            <div class="buyer-price center-align">$149.58</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

There will be some kind of "amount" of these li classes, which JavaScript adds. All those are stored under one class called: `row zmd-hierarchical-display in`
So there's is that  which has to match that removedname.. If it does match, then remove red lighten-1 white-text selected-item from parent class (it will be there, at the moment it is not in that HTML example.

Comment: Please rephrase the question.

Comment: I've reworked my question.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. `this` has meaning in the context of a loop or event handler, it's the current item in the loop or the target of the event. What is `this` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is what you want:

```
$(".item-card").find("img.title").removeClass("red lighten-1 white-text selected-item").each(function() {
    var removedname = $(this).text();
    // do something with removedname
});
```

Comment: I'll try to explain.. So I got an variable `removedname` which get's `original item name`. Then I got class which is called `red lighten-1 white-text selected-item` which is parent of that <img title=itemnamehere>. So, then it should find that same name from any of those div's with that img one and then if it's found then just remove that img parent class. I think it's still a bit unclear.

Comment: You need to update the question and show the HTML, then explain more clearly what you're trying to do with some actual values.

Comment: Edited the first post.